# Setting UISearchBar to minimal with translucency

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar

Is it possible to make a UISearchBar translucent with a background color and search field color that can be changed separately?

This is what I'm currently getting with a search style of minimal and a background of light blue. If I want the search field to be white, I have to not use minimal for the search style, but then my search bar isn't translucent.[image]

What can I do?